# How to display Details records of Selected Master Record on Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm new to Entity Framework and trying to learn the basics through simple examples.

These are my two tables with some of their columns:

**CUSTOMERS_BASE**:

```
CB_REFNO (primary key)
CB_NAME etc..
```

**ORDERS**:

```
OR_REFNO (primary key)
OR_M_REFNO (foreign key) to CONTACTS_BASE table etc..
```

I have inserted some sample data to both tables and what I want to accomplish now is to view all orders of a a customer on the datagridview.

I have a bindingNavigator, CONTACTS_BASEBindingSource and ORDERSBindingSource on my crud.

My code:

```
CONTACTS_BASEBindingSource.DataSource = lobo.CONTACTS_BASE.ToList();             
bindingNavigator1.BindingSource = CONTACTS_BASEBindingSource;
```

So now when I click next/previous buttons on the bindingNavigator I am able to view all the records that are on the CUSTOMERS_BASE table. But what do I have to do so that the ORDERSGridView will display each order record for each record on CONTACTS_BASE?

Thanks

Comment: In EFC2 i am using `Include("name")` where name is name of DBSet that you also want to include with that

Comment: Well, you can either `Include()` them in  `lobo.CONTACTS_BASE` or query them from the database when you navigate to another contact. Depends on numbers of records, network latency, whether you care about stale data, .... Hard to tell. Also, do yourself a favor and adhere to C# naming conventions for class and property names. Don't allow the database names to bleed into your code. That's what mapping is for.

Comment: but When I use include I still feed the CONTACTS_BASEBİndingSource right? I want to display orders on the ORDERSGridView. so don't I have to do something for it?